# What does "There I was, hip by association" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "There I was, hip by association" mean? And by the way, does "go some straight route" mean "create my career without his help" here?

> While going to college and thinking maybe I should **go some straight route**, I realized that after taking everything that ended in 101 or ology, there was nothing but music for me. So I left college, moved up to San Francisco, and started recording other people. I had no idea what I was doing. I got very lucky. I moved next door to a guy who was doing little 15-second spots for this new crazy cable channel. I did some of those - turns out it was MTV! **There I was, hip by association**. Ad agencies love cool. They tracked me down between who I was going to record next and writing music for commercials. It was very lucrative and a great business to get into. So pretty quickly I was able to turn my passion for music into a business.

([forbes.com)](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jimclash/2017/04/18/peter-buffett-warrens-youngest-son-says-growing-up-buffett-was-nothing-fancy/2/#3930019b39c5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *hip* in this context is an adjective; here is a definition listed in NOAD:

> **hip** (*adj.*) following the latest fashion, especially in popular music and clothes : *it's becoming hip to be environmentally conscious*.

The phrase *by association* means that something applies to you because you have some relationship to it. It's perhaps most often used in the phrase *guilty by association*. Again, from NOAD:

> **guilt by association** (*phrase*) guilt ascribed to someone not because of any evidence but because of their association with an offender.

So the author is saying that he was *hip by association*, that is, he was "in" or "cool" because of his association with something that was "in" or "cool" – in this case, MTV, which was new at the time.

---

As for "go some straight route," the word *straight* here means "conventional and ordinary," and the author is referring to the usual way of spending four years in college before embarking on a career.

Comment: "*The phrase by association means that something applies to you because you have some relationship to it. It's perhaps most often used in the phrase guilty by association.*" <-- It's not clear to me what the *it* refers to there. Are you saying that "*some description applies to you because it applies to something or someone you have some relationship with*"?

Comment: @AraucariaMan - Yes, that's it exactly.